# Tomcat Deployment with IntelliJ - Server is not connected

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I want to deploy a small web application with maven. I downloaded and configured tomcat and told IntelliJ to use it in Run/Debug config, as shown below. 
I also configured it to build the artifact "war exploded".

The poblem is, every time I run the project, I get an error saying:

> Artifact JDBCTest:war: Server is not connected. Deploy is not
>   available.

[Here's my dropbox with  error log, pom.xml, servlet class etc.](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wraww0931lnq8f3/AAAE3QybqFL3ZH5GauVj5rWSa?dl=0)

I could really use some advice.

[image: run/debug config].

Comment: working source code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7KRmrHNDtZ8cFNEaVBTS2JqYk0/view?usp=sharing Import to your IntelliJ IDEA, it just works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your source code structure is incorrect.

(1) Create folders structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
├── src/
│   ├── main/
│   │   ├── java/
│   │   │   └── servlet/
│   │   │       └── ServletHome.java
│   │   └── resources/
│   └── test/
│       ├── java/
│       └── resources/
└── webapp/
    ├── WEB-INF/
    │   └── web.xml
    └── hello.jsp
```

[image]

**ServletHome.java**

```
package servlet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@WebServlet(name = "servlethome", urlPatterns = {"/servlethome"})
public class ServletHome extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.getWriter().print("Hello World");
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(req, resp);
    }

}
```

You webapp can access at `http://localhost:8080/servlethome`
If you want see directly at homepage change to `urlPatterns = {"/"}`

(2) Add these line to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: thanks its working now but do you know how to show the hello.jsp content in tomcat?

Comment: If you want see content of `hello.jsp` at http://localhost:8080, inside file `ServletHome.java` change to from `urlPatterns = {"/servlethome"}` to `urlPatterns = {"/"}`.

Comment: i did it but its still showing hello world for me at localhost:18509

Comment: Ok. Let see your screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADwim.png again, Change **HTTP port:** from `18509` to default value `8080`.